# Mac OS gcc linking c and asm

Tags: c, macos, linker, operating-system, nasm

I decided to learn how to make own OS by tutorial, I wrote boot on NASM and kernel on C also linker.ld and makefile. When I try linking all together I have this kind of error:

`ld: library not found for -lgcc
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Also, I have installed binutils using homebrew but it doesn't help me. I have Mac OS 10.14

And this is my makefile:

```
CC = gcc

main: kernel.c linker.ld boot.asm
    nasm -felf32 boot.asm -o boot.o
    $(CC) -c kernel.c -o kernel.o -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra
    $(CC) -T linker.ld -o basilica.bin -ffreestanding -nostdlib boot.o kernel.o -lgcc
    cp basilica.bin isodir/boot/basilica.bin
    grub-mkrescue -o basilica.iso isodir

clean:
    rm ./*.o ./*.bin ./*.iso ./isodir/boot/*.bin
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this error: `ld: library not found for -lgcc`? Please help me.

Comment: Ah the good old `gcc` == `clang` alias on Mac OS. Dammit Applol.